# Why is my millisecond conversion wrong?

Tags: javascript, time

I have a timer app that counts time passed in milliseconds, converts that to a formatted string, then displays it. Elsewhere, I have a function that converts that same string to milliseconds for some other math I have to do. Seems counter-intuitive, I know, but it mostly works.

Anyways, this is the function that takes a string like 14.55 (14 seconds and ~550 milliseconds) and returns the time in milliseconds, but it's not doing it right.

```
function toMS(str) {
  if(str.includes(":")) {
    const [mins, secms] = str.split(":");
    const [sec, ms] = secms.split(".");
    return ((+mins * 60) + +sec) * 1000 + +ms;
  } else {
    const [sec, ms] = str.split(".");
    return (+sec) * 1000 + +ms;
  }
}
```

If I pass in something like 10.77, it returns 10077 instead of 10770 like it should. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I think you mean 10770 instead of 1770 - you've accidentally converted 10 seconds to 1 second in your expected output

Comment: I've edited the output he states, and the issue is that he's treating the number after the decimal as millisecs, when it's a decimal form.  so 10.77, the 77 is actually 770 ms, not 77.  @jingshao chen has the right answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That's what I meant. Sorry I've been working on this issue for hours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use parseFloat?

```
function toMS(str) {
  if(str.includes(":")) {
    const [mins, secms] = str.split(":");
    const sec = parseFloat(secms);
    return ((+mins * 60) + sec) * 1000;
  } else {
    return parseFloat(str) * 1000;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot, thanks! If it works I'll come back and mark it.

Comment: "sec is not defined"

Comment: Sorry, found a typo in my answer. Edited.

Comment: This works perfectly! I changed some of the formatting to fit my needs, but this is perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

0.1 seconds is equal to 100 ms, not 1ms. Remember that 0.1s can be also written as 1/10 of a second, `1/10 * 1000ms = 100ms`.

It means that you have to multiplicate the decimal part for 100 in order to get the correct result.

```
function toMS(str) {
  if(str.includes(":")) {
    const [mins, secms] = str.split(":");
    const [sec, ms] = secms.split(".");
    return ((+mins * 60) + +sec) * 1000 + +ms;
  } else {
    const [sec, ms] = str.split(".");
    return (+sec) * 1000 + ms * 100;
  }
}
```

Note: You don't need the `+` to convert your variable, since the `*` is enough to coerce it to `number`.

You can also apply the DRY principle in this way:

```
function toMS(str) {
  let mins = 0;
  if(str.includes(":")) {
    [mins, str] = str.split(":");
  } 
  const [sec, ms] = str.split(".");
  return mins * 60000 + sec * 1000 + ms * 100;
}
```

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but that code you posted is identical to mine. Did you mean to change something?

Comment: I don't think that's quite right either, because now all of my times are coming out wrong. I tried just doing toMS("10.77"); in the console, and it returned 17700 which is 17.7 seconds. Also, I can't @ your name for some reason.

Comment: This won't work if the string doesn't have exactly 2 decimal places.

Comment: @3ocene It doesn't really work even with exactly two, see my comment above. It's returning a number that's too high.

Comment: right, it would only work if there were exactly one decimal place, like .7, which gives 700.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about rounding errors with the `parseFloat` solution here's a pure string implementation:

```
ms = +(ms.concat("00").substring(0,3));
```

So, what are we doing?

1. Pad the millisecond string with "0". We pad with 2 zeros to cater for the following situations:

   a. There are more than 3 digits - in which case all the padded zeros will be ignored later

   b. There are exactly 3 digits - all the padded zeros will be ignored later

   c. There are exactly 2 digits - the extra zero will be ignored

   d. There is exactly 1 digit - both zeros are needed

   e. There are no digits at all - both zeros will be converted to `0` later
2. We take only the first 3 digits. This will automatically ignore both the case of any extra zeros and if ms was accidentally specified with more accuracy than required (eg. if someone entered 1.1234)
3. We convert to number using the unary `+` operator